# Exposed wire on outdoor Christmas lights

Tags: wiring

I am in Europe. I have outdoor Christmas lights. There are 720 white led lights (3v 0.015W), and the power supply unit is 32V 6W.

I have exposed wire close to the plug as shown attached.

The plug is located inside the house and is elevated higher than the entry point of the wire via a window vent (on a side note, is bringing the wire in via a window vent an issue?)

Should I immediately throw these lights in the bin or can I use insulation tape and be worry free?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this on the 120V side or on the DC side of the supply?

Comment: I don not have a clue. I am in Europe though.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the whole power supply then?

Comment: I have added more pictures, let me know if more would help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a photo showing the whole side of the supply, not just part of the label, would be useful

Comment: I have added another picture. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping me better my question @ThreePhasrEel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to tape this. If that plug is going into a 120V outlet, cut it off and replace the plug with one similar to the one below.

[image]

If that plug is going into the low side of the power supply, you can get some insulated splices at your home store and repair the wires.

**UPDATED**

Based on the new photos, the damaged wires are on the secondary, low voltage, side. So the insulated splices would be the way to go.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the photos, it's clear to me that the damage is on the low-voltage side. Also, looking at the plug on the adapter in the last photo, the OP is clearly not in North America.

Comment: @DoxyLover when I answered, there was only the first two photos. The OP mentioned he was in Europe so I tried to cover primary and secondary solutions.

Comment: @JACK Thanks for the answer and reviewing my updates. On the last picture, maybe you can see the cable is made up of two 'wires'. Do I put a splice around each one separately or the cable itself? Also, is there a reason you have suggested a splice over insulation tape? Also, I am realizing how little I know about electricity, can you direct me somewhere to learn about terms like "low side" etc. if you have time?

Comment: @atw You would have to splice each one. You actually cut the wire, strip off the insulation, insert the ends into each side of the splice and crimp. Do this to each wire but don't mix them up... Mark one wire with ink before cutting.  A splice instead of tape because you probably have damaged the actual copper wire and weakened it. so this way, you cut out the damaged part.  Google power supply, transformers, AC/DC adapters  for lots on info.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I understand. Accepted. One more thing If you can, what were the odds that I could have started a fire using the lights as they are currently?

Comment: "What are the odds"  That question belongs in Las Vegas.  At 188 mA  if the two wires were directly shorted out and isolated, the power supply would probably just burn out  without any fires but if just a strand of the wiring shorted out, it could arc and cause a spark or get red hot before burning up.  That being said, you never want to mess with damaged wiring because you never know what might happen.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your expertise Jack.